# Syntax error on express app.use

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have used this code with my node.js application with express but when uploading to Heroku I get an error when running.

```
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502448+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/routes/index.js:146
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502467+00:00 app[web.1]: app.use(({method, url}, rsp, next) => {
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502468+00:00 app[web.1]:          ^
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502468+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502469+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502469+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502470+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502471+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502471+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502472+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502473+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502473+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502474+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:8:14)
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502474+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-09-28T11:01:40.502475+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

My code is

```
app.use(({method, url}, rsp, next) => {
  rsp.on('finish', () => {
    console.log(`${rsp.statusCode} ${method} ${url}`);
  });
  next();
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json, do you specify the node engine?

```
"engines": {
    "node": "6.5.0"
}
```

I would have just added this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: I don't have an engines section in my package,json. All I have is {
  "name": "wc,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
    "connect-redis": "^3.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "feed-read": "0.0.1",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "http": "0.0.0",
  }
}

Comment: I will add this engines section and try again

Comment: Yep, make sure you include all of the required dependencies in your package.json, because when you upload to Heroku, it will install only the ones listed.  Also, are you missing a quotation closing " after the "name": "wc ?